Vuejs app mounted to FastAPI behind domain forwards back to HTTP
I'm having some issues with my vue.js app that I mounted to FastAPI.
I mount the built dist folder like this to my FastAPI server:
app.mount("/dist", StaticFiles(directory="../../frontend/src/dist", html=True), name="static")

I put the FastAPI server behind a reverse proxy as usual with my apps.
The FastAPI server is fully functional behind my reverse proxy.
Though, when I visit the /dist path where the frontend relies, it redirects me to http://{IP}:{PORT}/dist. Why is this so?
I tried using absolute and direct paths, but it keeps redirecting me to http://ip:port.
I've also set publicPath: '/dist/' in vue.config.js
EDIT: I use NginxProxyManager for the reverse proxy, so I have a plain default working reverse proxy setup. The Problem probably also can't rely on the reverse proxy, as the backend endpoints in FastAPI are fully working behind the domain and don't redirect me back to HTTP.
EDIT2: I've just checked, and requested things like css, js files etc. are available on the domain. So it seems like either a rounting issue between fastapi and the static assets or a problem within the frontend?

Does this or this help in any way?

@Chris Thanks for the links!
Tough I don't think they solve my problem.
First answer is not really possible, as it's a public project, which should be capable of running plain HTTP but also in HTTPS behind a domain.
Option 2 with the --proxy-headers have I also already found and tested, but without success.
As far as I can tell with my limited knowledge, I think this is rather a problem of the frontend and the vue.js build?
As the complete API written in FastAPI is fully working, just not the mounted frontend.
